# is there a way to light up the second led and not the first one?

Tags: analog, schematics, passive-components, analog-computer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXSYQe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this schematic I made I'm trying to light up a a series of LED's but not in sequence "not yet" what I want is to raise the start of with the lowest voltage a LED can operate on which will be sorta dim but this is ok and expected "im counting on that" and as you raise the voltage the second LED will light up BUT (here is where my question coming in!) not light up the first one so on and so on, maybe I want to turn LED #6 and NOT LED's 1 through 5 ?!

And yes I know I'm using a voltage divider and thats because I dont want all LED's to light up with a the same wavelength or same intensity

[image]

Using this schematic I'm not sure how to incorporate the photo-resistor so I cant include it in there but the idea is that when a particular LED lights up above a threshold the photo-diode will help meet the condition in a algorithm

Before anyone starts to yell at me talking about that there are other "conventional ways" I KNOW and while practical they might be doing it the conventional way is only practical for that application not mines specially where the objective is to use less I/O pins on the given MCU.  So if there is and I know theres gotta be a way to make this happen given the fact that we introduce the right components I know is possible, I can do this software wise but not hardware wise and this is why I'm here looking for help.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that wavelength is _not_ dependent on voltage or current, only LED type/construction and temperature (for the most part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a voltage comparator. Or multiple voltage comparators. Ideally, you'll just use a linear (or logarithmic) led driver like the [LM3914](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) in dot mode. Which is just a bunch of comparators chained together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply but i updated a "better?" version of what i need using circuitLab, like i said i needed to add a photodiode but im not sure i even have it facing the led correctly im really new to this programs and by voltage comparator you mean a op amp  or a 555 timer?

Comment: @frank a timer is not a comparator. Op amps can be wired as comparators, but there are dedicated comparator ICs that can be used. I have no idea what you want to do with those photodiode

Comment: can you please confirm that this is what you mean i need please ? http://www.ebay.com/itm/10Pcs-LED-Display-Driver-IC-NSC-DIP-18-LM3914N-1-LM3914N-1-NOPB-good-quality-/262136736187?hash=item3d089129bb:g:FJQAAOSwLN5WhJwR

Comment: @Frank yes, that's *supposedly* a lm3914, not sure if its real or counterfeit, but that's a linear led bar/dot graph IC. You can google or youtube `lm3914` for plenty of examples on how to wire it and how it looks in dot mode.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxio_dP_ARg

Comment: thanks, is because i keep seeing the LM3917N and its throwing me off cuz you said the LM3917 not 3917N

Comment: @Frank LM is a prefix. N is a suffix, meaning Plastic DIP Throughhole packaging. 3914 has a linear response. 3915 has a logarithmic response. 3916 is a VU/Audio response. 3917 is nothing I know of.

Comment: i know i mess'up i meant to say 3914 not 3917 but yeah my point was that i keep seeing the 3914N and you did not mentioned that in the answer so i thought this is a whole completely different one, but your saying that with this IC i should be able to turn one one led in a array of 10 or so and not the rest before or after that one that i might pick ? using that schematic above?

Comment: @Frank yes. look at the youtube video I link to. And you don't have to use 10 leds, you can use just 3 or 7 or whatever if you want.